# Geo-Nodes Extrude Mesh different amount

Tags: geometry-nodes, extrude

I am trying to control the amount of extrusion from the extrude mesh node. I am extruding the edges. I tried this setup to to have some thinner and some thiccer parts, but it does not work.[image]

This is the object with uniform extrusion scale, which i want to manipulate.
(The changing thickness in the picture comes from Rotation, not from the actual extrusion)

[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: Looks OK... but _Spline Factor_ isn't a native attribute of a mesh-line, any more than _Normal_ is, (in the way a curve understands it,) so the factor has to be captured on the mesh-points in the same way as you've captured the normal, and _then_  put through your _Float Curve_ .

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot! :)